# how to get queryParams in subscribe from resolver

Tags: html, angular, typescript

here is my ngOnInit (i am getting the data from a resolver)-

```
ngOnInit() {
    const products = this.route.snapshot.data['users'] as IProductInterface[];
    this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
  }
```

my getter -

```
public getProduct() {
    return this._products;
  }
```

here is how im displaying data on html -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of getProduct()">
        <span class="productInfo__title">{{ product.getTitle() }}</span>
</ng-container>
```

i would like to change that to subscribe because i want that to update whenever im changing the query. how can i do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Data } from '@angular/router';
....
....

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data: Data) => {
        const products = data['users'] as IProductInterface[];
        this._products = products.map((product) => new Product(product));
    })    
}
```

Comment: still does not refresh when im clicking.